# React component not recognized as string or class function

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to build a component that could be used as a npm package, and have constructed a example application to test and demonstrate usage.  This results in [image]

I have two files: in the package source: `PDF` and `index`.  PDF defines the component and exports at the end with

```
export default PDF;
```

`index.js` is just `export {default} from './PDF';`

## EDIT - PDF file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Viewer from './Viewer';
import pdfjsLib from './../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack'

class PDF extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            document: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.props.file);
        loadingTask.promise.then(document => {
            console.log('Loaded Document');
            console.log(document);
            this.setState({
                document: document
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Viewer doc={this.state.document}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export {PDF};
```

Webpack build configuration is

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'index': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/lib'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: ['url-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

which creates a `/lib` folder for the build artifacts.

I then symlink this build folder to `project/example/node_modules/react-pdf` and use it in the sample demonstration as below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PDF from 'react-pdf';

class Viewer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            file: '//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-test/test-file-43092.pdf'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <PDF document={this.state.file}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Viewer;
```

But that resulted in the screenshot at the start.

Other things I've tried:

- project/src/index.js `export {PDF} from './PDF'`;
- project/src/index.js `export {PDF as default} from './PDF';`
- project/src/PDF.js `export {PDF};`
- project/example/src/Viewer.js `import {PDF} from 'react-pdf'`;

but nothing has worked.  I suspect this has to do with the webpack build configuration, but nothing pops out at me.

Comment: can you please upload to github, so we can test it.

Comment: Have you tried in index.js `import PDF from './PDF'; export default PDF;`

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha, no can do :-/  this is a work project, and no public github repo available (and management won't allow me to fork on my personal account)

Comment: @FinbarrO'B, same issue :-/

Comment: ok.. np... so can you update question with `pdf` file source code ?

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha done

Answer (score 0):

Just try this in your `PDF` class

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Viewer from './Viewer';
import pdfjsLib from './../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack'

export class PDF extends Component { //Update export inline

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            document: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.props.file);
        loadingTask.promise.then(document => {
            console.log('Loaded Document');
            console.log(document);
            this.setState({
                document: document
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Viewer doc={this.state.document}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

//export {PDF}; // remove this line
```